# Data points not showing up in scatterplot

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I'm currently attempting to create a scatterplot with date related summed values. This same procedure has worked for displaying yearly values but does not seem to work.

This is the current code for the date related plot

```
  benthos = WE_Benthos_Cleaned_mg_2

#Remove NA rows and make NA values that should be 0 into 0
benthos = benthos[!benthos$lakeID=='NA',]
benthos$Drymassweight_Biomass[is.na(benthos$Drymassweight_Biomass)] = 0
#First, lets add all the insect biomass together per station and sampling event
benSum = ddply(benthos, c("lakeID","date","stationID","depth","repID"), summarise,
               sumDM_mg = sum(Drymassweight_Biomass,na.rm=T))
#To look at general patterns in biomass, we are going to get a mean value for the different habitats for each year 
benMeandate = ddply(benSum, c("lakeID","depth","date"), summarise,
                N = length(sumDM_mg),
                meanDM = mean(sumDM_mg,na.rm=T),
                sd = sd(sumDM_mg,na.rm=T),
                SE = (sd / sqrt(N)))

#Add confidence interval columns 
benMeandate$Upper2SE = benMeandate$meanDM+1.96*benMeandate$SE
benMeandate$Lower2SE = benMeandate$meanDM-1.96*benMeandate$SE

#Jitter 
benMeandate$date[benMeandate$lakeID=="WE2"] = benMeandate$year[benMeandate$lakeID=="WE2"] + 0.05
benMeandate$date[benMeandate$lakeID=="WE1"] = benMeandate$year[benMeandate$lakeID=="WE1"] - 0.05

#Plot mean biomass/year - Hypo
benMeandate_hypo = benMeandate[benMeandate$depth=='hypolimnion',]
plot(benMeandate_hypo$date,benMeandate_hypo$meanDM,col=ifelse(benMeandate_hypo$lakeID=="WE2",'black','gray'),
     pch=ifelse(benMeandate_hypo$lakeID=="WE2",21,24),bg=ifelse(benMeandate_hypo$lakeID=="WE2","black","gray"),ylim=c(-0.04,0.6),xlim=c(2016,2021),
     ylab = "Mean Biomass (mg-AFDM)",xlab="Year",xaxt="n")
abline(v=2018.5,lty=2)
axis(1, xaxp=c(2017, 2020, 3), las=1)
arrows(benMeandate_hypo$date,benMeandate_hypo$Lower2SE,benMeandate_hypo$date,benMeandate_hypo$Upper2SE, code=3, length=0.02, angle = 90,
       col=ifelse(benMeandate_hypo$lakeID=="WE2",'black','gray'))
```

And here is a portion of the data

| lakeID | depth | year | N | meanDM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| WE1 | hypolimnion | 2016.95 | 6 | 0.002262546 |
| WE1 | hypolimnion | 2017.95 | 11 | 0.032788214 |
| WE1 | hypolimnion | 2018.95 | 5 | 0.049376644 |
| WE1 | hypolimnion | 2019.95 | 13 | 0.286644714 |
| WE2 | hypolimnion | 2017.05 | 3 | 0.016292398 |
| WE2 | hypolimnion | 2018.05 | 10 | 0.059015917 |
| WE2 | hypolimnion | 2019.05 | 5 | 0.131525626 |
| WE2 | hypolimnion | 2020.05 | 11 | 0.014298989 |

I'm using the following packages

`library(readxl) library(plyr) library(lubridate)`

I'm sure i'm missing something here

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. We can't reproduce your error because we don't know what your data looks like, and which packages you are using. Could you create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Hi! Sorry about the missing info. Hopefully the data is sufficient now.

Comment: Thanks, but we still can't reproduce this - we don't know the content of many columns mentioned in your code: `date` (most importantly, as you're trying to plot it) but also `Drymassweight_Biomass`, `stationID`, `repID`. Also, it looks like you haven't shared `WE_Benthos_Cleaned_mg_2` (you calculate `meanDM`). Can you share a portion of your whole dataset? If you run `dput(head(WE_Benthos_Cleaned_mg_2))` and copy and paste the result here, we will be able to see the first 6 rows of your dataset and will be able to help you.